# Definition of Tensor Product of V-spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I'm reading a book on tensors and it says the following:

[image]

I'm still a bit confused on Definition 1.1
I never really learned what a free group was. I was just basically told to think of it as a group on letters. Anyways I'd like to understand what a quotient of a free abelian group is and also maybe a specific example or two. Someone told me that the definition is really never used and is just for technical purposes and to just forget about it. What does it mean that it is generated by elements of that form? I noticed that if I set the right hand side to 0 then we basically have bilinearity. I think an example or two or three could illuminate this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The *free abelian group* generated by some set $A$ consists of formal expressions of the form

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n m_i a_i $$
where the $m_i$ are integers, and $a_i \in A$ (and $n$ can be any positive integer). Think of it like a vector space, where $A$ is the basis, but instead of having real number coefficients, you are only allowed integer coefficients.

For example, if $A = \{a,b\}$ only has two elements, then every element of the free abelian group generated by $A$ is of the form $ma + nb$ for integers $m$ and $n$.

For another example (but where $A$ is infinite), consider $A = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots\}$, thinking of "$x^k$" as formal symbols. Then the free abelian group generated by $A$ is the set of polynomials with integer coefficients, since any polynomial is a (finite) sum of terms which look like $c \, x^k$ for some integer $c$.

The example for the tensor product considers the free abelian group generated by $M \times N$. This means a generic element looks like
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n k_i \, (m_i,n_i) $$
where $n$ is some positive integer, $k_i$ are integers, and $m_i \in M$, $n_i \in N$. Again, using the vector space analogy, it's like a vector space (with integer coefficients), where the whole infinite set $M \times N$ is the basis.

Now, a "*quotient*" of a free abelian group informally means you take certain elements and declare them to be equal to zero.

For example, when $A = \{a,b\}$, if you quotient by the subgroup generated by $a-b$, that means you are setting $a-b=0$, which would imply $a=b$. So in the quotient, since $a=b$, all elements can just be expressed as $m a$ for some integer $m$.

In the tensor product example, the elements of the form $(i)$, $(ii)$, and $(iii)$ are just ensuring that in the quotient, you have the relations:
$$
\begin {align*}
(m_1+m_2,n) &= (m_1,n) + (m_2,n) \\
(m,n_1+n_2) &= (m,n_1) + (m,n_2) \\
(rm,n) &= (m,rn)
\end {align*}
$$